# Drawer with navigation header

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I decide to give a try to the new react native navigator: [link](https://reactnavigation.org)
What I am trying to do is to have a header with hamburger and when pressing the hamburger the drawer to be shown (something standard for every mobile application). Here is what I did:

```
const AppDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeFeed },
    Notifications: { screen: Notifications }
});

const App = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: AppDrawer }
});

AppDrawer.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home Feed',
    header: () => ({
        // Render a button on the right side of the header
        // When pressed switches the screen to edit mode.
        left: (
            <Button
                title={'Drawer'}
            />
        ),
        tintColor: '#007AFF',
    })
};
```

And here is the result:

[image]

The drawer is under the header when opened. Also the left button is not visible, the tint color is not changing.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: While there is no direct question I will point out a few things that may be giving you issues.

1. you are making your drawernavigator a child of a stacknavigator, thus you have a header over your drawer. 

2. those navigationOption property should be assigned to one of your screens (HomeFeed or Notifications) rather than your DrawerNavigator. 

hope that helps some